# Firebase security when not using Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building apps using Firebase (Storage, Functions, Hosting, Real-Time Database and Firestore). In the apps, the user authenticates using a third-party library (like Google connect but not Google).

I don't know how to protect my database because I am not using Firebase Authentication. How can I use this third party authentication to protect data for example? Maybe I need to create a user manually and attach information to him so that this info will be available in the Security Rules editor?

Thanks

Comment: You can integrate a custom authentication system into Firebase auth. Have you had a chance to check this out yet? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth - this link is for iOS, but you can find a guide for Android and Web in their docs as well.

Comment: I had a look, that requires to have my own auth server, which I don't. The auth is done by a third party...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can secure your database or storage  without a form of authentication.

Now firebase provides multiple methods of authentication (email , google, custom , anonymous .....).

**What you might want:**

You might want to add custom login to your users in which they get registered with extra data that you provide. And they will still get a user id that you will use to check in the rules to allow read and writes along with some custom data you provided while registration (so you can check these data from the rules).